# Pysal issue module has no attribute 'open'

Tags: geospatial, python-module, pysal

I have an issue with the 'Pysal' library. I can successfully install Pysal and import it. However, whenever I use the function of Pysal , for example, opening a file by using 'open', then I will get an issue and it shows that 'module 'pysal' has no attribute 'open' '.Even I use other attributes instead of 'open', I will still get the issue. How should I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What version of pysal are you using? Please see the migration guide if using the latest release.

“pysal.open will change to pysal.lib.io.open”
https://github.com/pysal/pysal/blob/master/MIGRATING.md

Comment: Thanks you! It finally worked